# How to show and hide specific Column?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I have a `mat-table` with `mat-menu`:

```html
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
        <span>Index</span>
      </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
        <mat-icon>voicemail</mat-icon>
        <span>Created At</span>
      </button>
</mat-menu>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let vms"> {{vms.index}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="createdAt">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created At </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let vms">{{vms.vm_created_at}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I also have a menu that shows the list of `displayedCloumns`, I am trying to show and hide the columns when I click the menu. For e.g. `index` or `createdAt`

`component`

```
displayedColumns = ['index', 'createdAt'];
dataSource;
```

The example in the Angular material docs explains, show, and hide the random column and uses `slice` and `push`.

I am trying to `show` and `hide` the specific column on click.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are several ways to do this, but one way I see is to have each menu item's click event pass an associated column name to a function that performs the column hiding or showing. The example below doesn't order the columns (since `splice` and `push` are used, column hiding/showing always happens at the last column of the table), but adding additional logic to maintain a specific order shouldn't be too much of a change.

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1trukw)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same few weeks ago! Any solution?

Comment: did you take a look at the example StackBlitz I posted to see if that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group of toggle buttons in your view and use their value to point to the columns like this:

```
<mat-button-toggle-group [multiple]="true" group="matButtonToggleGroup">
  <mat-button-toggle value="colname">
    <span>button name</span>
  </mat-button-toggle>
       .......
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

Then, you can toggle the columns by toggling the buttons by adding the following line in your ts file:

```
@ViewChild('group') toggle: MatButtonToggle;
```

See the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/poc-column-selector?file=app%2Ftable-basic-flex-example.ts)

Answer (score 0):

A solution I used is to create a remove function that can be reused for each column.

my.component.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['thatParticularColumn'];
columnsToDisplay: string[] = this.displayedColumns.slice();

removeThatParticularColumn() {
 this.remove('thatParticularColumn');
}

remove(ele: string) {
 let index = this.columnsToDisplay.indexOf(ele);
 if (index > -1) {
    this.columnsToDisplay.splice(index, 1);
 }
}
```

my.component.html

```
<mat-table>
   </ng-container matColumnDef="thatParticularColumn">
      ...
   </ng-container>
   <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
   <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
<mat-table>

<button mat-button (click)="removeThatParticularColumn()"> Hide That Particular Column </button>
```

NB: Don't forget to import the proper modules.